# DS2401 Mcdata switch offline

Tags: storage, switch

I've two DS2401 Mcdata switches. One is pinging fine and accessible while the other is not.switch is not responding to ping or http requests.

I'm remotely managing this switch. Is there a way I can troubleshoot this issue with the operation team?

Answer (score 2):

Get a known-working laptop, plug it directly into the SAN switch's LAN port, set the laptop IP accordingly, test, if that works then the problem is downstream of the SAN switch, if it doesn't work it's the IP setup on the SAN switch so fix that.

If it wasnt the SAN switch then get the same laptop, plug it into the SAN switch's LAN switch port, set the laptop's IP accordingly, test, if this works you have a patching problem (so fix that), if not you have a LAN switch port problem; either a dead port or a misconfigured port/switch.

The end.

Comment: Hi chopper:  I 'm little unclear of the second part of your suggestion.

Comment: I 'll 've a guy connect from PC/Laptop LAN Port to LAN Port of the SAN switch (DS2401) with Crossover cable direct to see if a Ping is successfull ?Now, if it works does it mean downstreaming of the SAN switch? What exactly is meant by" downstreaming of the SAN switch"..appreciate your response / and time

Comment: Think of the problem being only one of three things; the SAN switch config, the LAN switch config or the cabling between. Use the laptop to test the first two, if it's not one of those it'll be the cabling.

Comment: Hello Chopper; I unplugged the switch from the power supply, waited about a minute plus and powered the switch back up. Still same issue, ports 0-7 seem to be sending and receiving but ports 8-23 are not. I believe this should be considered a hardware issue and Switch 1 replaced? please suggest